# разбить каждую строку по пробелам и добавить в массив только первое значение

Tags: java

у меня есть набор значений в текстовом файле

```
1529666255304 123456789 128.158.234.15    
1529666289305 123456799 123.148.214.19    
......
```

все они String

как записать в массив только первые значения т е

```
1529666255304    
1529666289305    
.....
```

вот что я накалякал

```
    String [] mass;
            try {
                BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:file.txt"));
                String sCurrentLine;

                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    mass = sCurrentLine.trim().split("\\s+");

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делайте разделение, проверяйте количество элементов и добавляйте первый:

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/file.txt"));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] parts = line.trim().split("\\s+");
        if (parts.length > 0) {
            items.add(parts[0]);
        }

    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(items);
```

Comment: почему выводит сначала запятую? т е [, 1553609880, 1553609881, 1553609882, 1553609883, 1553609884, 1553609885, 1553609886, 1553609887, 1553609888, 1553609889]

Comment: Похоже, пустой элемент добавился... проверьте если ли что странного у вас строкой выше `1553609880`, еще можно добавить проверку: `if (parts.length > 0 && !parts[0].isEmpty()) {` либо проверять на пустоту строку `line.trim()`

Comment: спасибо, && !parts[0].isEmpty() помогло

Answer (score 1):

С помощью стримов

```java
String[] result = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/file.txt")).lines()
        .map(s -> s.trim().split("\\s+")[0])
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

С помощью контейнера с последующим преобразованием в массив

```java
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/file.txt"));
String sCurrentLine;
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(sCurrentLine.trim().split("\\s+")[0]);
}

String[] result = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
```